# Generating multiple thumbnails efficiently from a single Image stream

Tags: java, image-processing, parallel-processing, thumbnails

I have an image upload servlet which receives uploaded images via HTTP POST and are high resolution images with size varying from 5 MB - 75 MB. The image data is read from the request input stream and and saved onto a local disk. I am looking for a efficient mechanism to generate thumbnails in parallel (or part sequential if not fully parallel) of varied sizes (4-5 different sizes of which the largest is the webimage - 1024x768) from the request inputstream along with saving the stream into disk as original uploaded file.

What I could think of till now is -

1. Save the original stream as image file to disk.
2. Generate webimage (1024x768) which is the largest among the lot of thumbnails.
3. Then use this to generate subsequent smaller images as it would be faster.

Could someone please suggest a better effcient way ? The most desired approach would be to do this synchronously but async is also fine if its very efficient.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated preferably in Java.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite an interesting question as it has a number of points of optimisation.

Your idea about generating a smaller image then generating the thumbnails off that is probably a good one but the first thing I would say is if you have a 75MB image then it is clearly far bigger than 1024x768 - most likely some multiple of it, in which case you want to make certain you scale the image using SCALE_FAST ([Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)). What you want to achieve is that the scaling chops the image down to a smaller size by discarding pixels rather than trying to do anything nicer-looking (and much more expensive) like area averaging.  You may even be able to get it to go faster by grabbing the int[] for the image and sampling every Nth element to create a new int[] for a new image, scaled down by some factor.

At that point you will have a smaller image, say roughly 2000 by 2000.  You can then take that image and scale it using something nicer looking for the actual thumbnails like SCALE_SMOOTH.

I would say that you should *not* write it to disk if at all possible (during processing anyway).  If you can do the operation in memory it will be far faster and that is doubly important where there is parallelism.  Unless your server is running an SSD then having two disk-heavy operations running at the same time (like two of these images being rescaled at the same time or one image being rescaled to two different sizes) will force your disk to thrash (since the spindle can only read one stream at a time).  You will then be at the mercy of your seek time and you'll quickly find that serialising all the operations will be far faster than doing multiple at once.

I would say rescale them in memory then write them (synchronized) to an ArrayList then have another thread reading those images sequentially and storing them.  If you're not sure what I mean then have a look at my answer to another question here:

[Producer Consumer solution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288479/how-to-solve-the-producer-consumer-using-semaphores/8289614#8289614)

This way you parallelise where its useful (CPU operations) and you do the file writes sequentially (avoiding thrashing).

Having said that you need to ask yourself if parallelising is going to benefit you at all.  Does your server have multiple CPUs/Cores?  If not then this is all moot and you should just not bother threading anything because it will only lose you time.

Further to this, if you are expecting a lot of these images to get uploaded at once then you may not need to parallellise the processing of each image since you will end up with multiple web server threads all processing one image each most of the time and that will give you good CPU utilisation across more than one core anyway.  For example if you expect that at any one time there will be 4 images being uploaded constantly then this would utilise 4 cores just fine without further parallelisation.

One last note would be that when you are rescaling the images, once you have the intermediate image you can set the previous image to null to facilitate garbage collection, meaning when you generate the thumbnails you will only have the intermediate image in memory, not the original large size one.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got this right,

You have one large image and want to perform different operations on it at the same time. Some operations involve disk IO.

**Option 1,** 
 Start 1 thread to save the original hi res image to disk. This will take a long time compared to other operations because disk writing is slow.
 Start other threads to create thumbnails of desired size. You need to resize the original image. I believe this can be done by cloning the bytes of the original image (in java I assume BufferedImage). You can then resize the clones according to the sizes you wish. The resizing operation is faster compared to writing to disk.

If you have 1 thread per thumbnail, you can use these threads to save their thumbnails to disk. The problem is that you will be done making the thumbnails fast, and all these threads will be writing to disk almost at once. The problem here is that they might be sent to different disk locations, instead of being grouped in the same physical area on disk (locality issue). The result is that, the disk writes will be even slower than not doing this in parallel because the disk has to seek the new location and write a bit of data, then the CPU does context switch and takes another thread which will write to another part of the disk (so another seek) and so on. So this idea is slow.

Note: use ExecutorService which has a thread pool, instead of individual threads. In my example I used 1 thread per thumbnail because it makes it easier to explain.

**Option 2,** 
 Another way you can do it is designate one thread to do disk writing, and a few other worker threads to do resizing. Cache all thmubnails into a list from which the thread which writes to disk will take them one by one and write them out.

**Option 3,** 
 Lastly, if you have multiple disks, you can give each thread a disk to write to, then all writes will be in parallel (more or less).

If you have RAID, the writes will be faster, but not as fast as I just mentioned above because the files are written in series not in parallel. RAID parallelizes writing parts of the same file (to different disks at once).