# Multithreading with Semaphor, Mutex and PThread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

Me and a friend are currently working on basic multithreading examples for university in c. We're supposed to solve the producer/consumer problem with a multithreaded buffer. We've got a working version using mutex and conditional variables, but trying to solve this ***using semaphores and mutex were having three major problems.***

**Problem 1**: If we start the consumer first he sometimes randomly consumes an invalid char and crashes.

**Problem 2:** If we start the producer first, he sometimes doesnt produce any chars until the consumer is started, which leads to problem 1.

**Problem 3:** Our producers dont fill the whole buffer, after every insertion in the buffer the consumer is consuming, no matter how many producers there are.

According to our given pseudocode-examples atleast problem 2&3 shouldnt be existing. Im really grateful for any answers, since Im not able to find the mistake at the moment.

Consumer:

```
void *consumer_sem(void *args) {
    printf("cons started\n");
    char c;

    while (cons_running) {
        sem_wait(occupied);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        c = consume();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(free);

        printf("consumer consumed %c\n\n", c);
        sleep(2);
    }   
}
```

Producer:

```
void *producer1_sem(void *args) {    
    printf("prod1 started\n");    
    char c;    
    int index=0;

    while (prod1_running) {    
        c = lowercase[index];    
        index=next(index);    

        sem_wait(free);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        add(c);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);    
        sem_post(occupied);

        printf("producer1 produced something!\n");    
        printf("%d elements in buffer\n\n",getElemsInBuffer());   
        sleep(3);    
    }    
}
```

main:

```
sem_t *occupied, *free;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(void) {
    occupied=sem_open("/occupied", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    free=sem_open("/free", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);

    //some unrelated code called

    pthread_create(&thread_ids[0], NULL, producer1_sem, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_ids[1], NULL, producer2_sem, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread_ids[2], NULL, consumer_cond, NULL);

}
```

Comment: strongly suggest searching `stackoverflow.com` for representative examples of this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the producer-consumer using semaphores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288479/how-to-solve-the-producer-consumer-using-semaphores)

Comment: @user3629249: Marking "C" question to be duplicate of "Java" question isn't wise: beginners, who start from C language, usually don't know Java, so they just cannot understand the referenced question.

Comment: @user3629249 Ive checked the link you sent out and it doesnt seem to apply to my problem. If you look at the latest answer its basically a very similar approach, but it doesnt help me finding the mistake in this C version, which should be correct according to the keynote of our professor. @

Comment: @tsyvarev I actually do know java, but I think my problem here comes down to not being too familiar with linux and posix yet. I think we somehow have a problem with our semaphore initialization, but we cant pin down our mistake. Since we initialize occupied with 0 the consumer shouldnt be able to produce the first problem.

Comment: You create semaphore with [sem_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) function, which actually creates *global* (*named*) semaphore, existed until `sem_unlink` is called. As your code doesn't call this function, next program run you just **reuse already existed semaphore**, and its value isn't *reseted*. If you need a semaphore just for inter-thread communication, use [sem_init](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) - such semaphore is automatically destroyed when the program exists.

Comment: @Tsyvarev This comment just solved all of my listed problems, I just started using sem_init and declared occupied & free as sem_t instead of pointers and my problems are gone. Thank you very much, if you would repost your comment as an actual answer I'd upvote it.

Comment: My friend just told me he used sem_open so the code would run on OSX since it doesnt support sem_init and unnamed semaphores. Atleast now we understand why we had this problem and how to prevent  it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [sem_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) creates global (*named*) semaphore, which exists until `sem_unlink()` is called.

When you run your program second time (and further), `sem_open` **reuses already existed semaphore**, and its value isn't reseted. You can easily detect that:

```
// With O_EXCL opening already existed semaphore will fail.
occupied=sem_open("/occupied", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
if(occupied == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("Failed to create new semaphore");
    exit(1);
}
```

Actually, when a semaphore is used only by single process (but many threads), it is sufficient to initialize it with `sem_init`:

```
sem_t occupied;
//...
int main()
{
    sem_init(&occupied, 0 /* do not share between processes*/, 0 /* initial value*/);
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, you may destroy old semaphore before attempt to create new one:

```
// Destroy the semaphore if it exists.
sem_unlink("/occupied");
// Create the semaphore again.
occupied = sem_open("/occupied", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I setup and ran (via a `make` file) the posted code;

Here is the `makefile.mak` I used, which I ran via `make -f makefile.mak`

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

#
# macro of all *.c files
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
#OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
#INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)




MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      := mv

#LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib


DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS     :=

.PSEUDO: all
all:  gestore personA personB

#
# link the .o files into the executable
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
getstore: getstore.o
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #

personA: personA.o
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #

personB: personB.o
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) -o $@ $^  $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #

#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makfile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I.
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    #

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.d
    rm -f getstore
    rm -f personA
    rm -f personB
    # ========== DONE ==========

# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependencies for that .c file
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```